# Keep window ratio in electronjs

Tags: javascript, electron

How can I keep the window width and height aspect ratio in electron?

For example, a square shape that can be resized by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [`win.setAspectRatio`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetaspectratioaspectratio-extrasize-macos) API for the `BrowserWindow`.

Note that it's currently only available on macOS on the latest stable (Electron 8.2.1), but should be available on Linux as of Electron 9.

[PR #18306](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/18306) attempts to add support for Windows, but hasn't been accepted yet.

EDIT: This has been added to Electron 11 via [PR #26941](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/26941).

Comment: I hope they will add it for windows too.

Comment: I was also using 'setAspectRation()' but it seems not working when we click on zoom/maximized until the window is resized.

Comment: @wasitShafi feel free to check the issue tracker for bugs if you're encountering bad behaviour

Comment: @Erick the bug i was facing has been fixed now, checkout issue: [#30277](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/30277)

Answer (score 2):

```
var resizeTimeout;
mainWindow.on('resize', (e)=>{
    clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
    resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        var size = mainWindow.getSize();
        mainWindow.setSize(size[0], parseInt(size[0] * 9 / 16));
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer.